# How can I get RequestMethod of ServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

I have ServletRequest, which client machine sent. How to know which one it is: `GET` `POST` `UPDATE` or `DELETE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring MVC and your comunication protocol is HTTP, you don't need use ServletRequest, you can use directly HttpServletRequest in your method like this:

```
public ModelAndView index(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
```

But if you need use ServletRequest and you are sure your comunication protocol is HTTP you can cast your ServletRequest to HttlServletRequest and use getMethod() like Shriram said.

Answer (score 13):

HttpServletRequest contains getMethod() which returns the name of the HTTP method with which this request was made, for example, GET, POST, or PUT

Comment: just one question. HtttServletRequest contains this method yes. If I cast my ServletRequest to HttpServletRequest it will work. My question is, can my ServletRequest be not instance of HttpServletRequest?